# Oracle Snapins or modules availability

Tags: powershell, pssnapin

I need to write a powershell script which runs various commands on an oracle server.
Are there Snapins or modules available for oracle like there are for SQL server etc?

I did my research but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of this blog: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/04/use-oracle-odp-net-and-powershell-to-simplify-data-access/

It makes reference to "Oracle Managed DataAccess provider OPD.NET" - this is what I've used when I've needed to interact with Oracle databases